# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string

Tags: java, hadoop

```
**“Path inputPath = new Path(job.get(KnnDriver.QUERY_DIR_PROPERTY));”**//it  gives  out   error。
    if (inputPath == null)
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ERROR: query directory not set");
    job.setInputFormat(NonSplitableTextInputFormat.class);
    NonSplitableTextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
    Path outputPath = new Path(job.get(KnnDriver.RESULT_DIR_PROPERTY));
    FileSystem.get(job).delete(outputPath, true);
    // Change to FileOutputFormat to see output

    job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

    KnnDriver.run(job);
}
```

I  have  taged  the   error  in  the  text。
The  following   will   be the   static  constant  I have set  in  knnDriver.

```
public static final String QUERY_DIR_PROPERTY = "knn.query.dir";
public static final String RESULT_DIR_PROPERTY = "knn.result.dir";
public static final String THRESHOLD_PROPERTY = "knn.sim.threshold";
```

Comment: please  give  some  effctive  suggestion.  thanks

Comment: How about using `if(inputPath != null){}else{}` to catch the error.

Comment: I  have  tried  It what you have said.It doesn't works  with the same error in the picture above.

Comment: I can run it through give the path as a constant,such as "knn.query.dir",without the final string in the other class.I don't the reason,but it works.

Comment: thanks for your answer to my  question.

Comment: Don't look for the black swan! Just make sure it never comes lol

Comment: I posted the answer, so you can check it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking to see if the variable is null first, and then doing whatever you need, just do whatever you need as long as it's **not** null. This eliminates the need to check to see if a variable is "exactly" equal to something. It creates complications.

To avoid this, use an if statement that does what was stated above.

```
if(inputPath != null){
//Whatever you want
}else{
//However you want to catch it
}
```

Basically, you're not looking for the black swan anymore, but just checking that there aren't any. This approach is much less problematic and should be used instead of the way you did.